# Windows API: Guess the next caret position

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently writing a function to get the current line/column of an EDIT control, and I'm stuck on a problem:
If I use WM_KEYUP to handle the caret position, the coordinates are valid but it can't be updated every "frame" since it waits for the user to release the pressed key
If I use WM_KEYDOWN, GetCaretPos returns the "previous" position of the caret (well, it's an obvious issue since it hasn't moved yet.)
Is there anything I can do to guess the next position of a caret? is it efficient if I just use EM_GETSEL?

```cpp
LRESULT Edit::HandleMessage(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        // Get character position from the mouse cursor's position (currently, there's no conversion of the coordinates if the mouse cursor is out of bound)
        POINT pntMousePos{ 0 };
        pntMousePos.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        pntMousePos.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
        LRESULT notifyValue = this->Notify(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MAKELPARAM(pntMousePos.x, pntMousePos.y));
        int lineIdx = static_cast<int>(this->Notify<int, LPARAM>(EM_LINEINDEX, -1));
        if (lineIdx == NULL) {
            DWORD beg, end;
            lineIdx = Notify(EM_GETSEL, &beg, &end);
        }
        m_caretPos.line = HIWORD(notifyValue) + 1;
        m_caretPos.column = (LOWORD(notifyValue) - lineIdx) + 1;
        // Send a custom message to the main window
        SendMessage(GetParent(m_parent) /*The EDIT control is actually a child of a tab control that is itself a child of the main window, ignore this */, CEM_GETLINEINFO, MAKEWPARAM(m_caretPos.line, m_caretPos.column), 0);
    }
    break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        // Get Character position from the carret's position
        // Get text metric (doesn't work so I removed some lines)
        TEXTMETRIC tm{0};
        HDC hdc = GetDC(m_self);
        SelectObject(hdc, this->m_fnt);
        GetTextMetricsW(hdc, &tm);
        ReleaseDC(m_self, hdc);

        POINT caretPos{ 0 };
        GetCaretPos(&caretPos);
        LRESULT notifyValue = this->Notify(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MAKELPARAM(caretPos.x, caretPos.y));
        int lineIdx = static_cast<int>(this->Notify<int, LPARAM>(EM_LINEINDEX, -1));
        m_caretPos.line = HIWORD(notifyValue) + 1;
        m_caretPos.column = (LOWORD(notifyValue) - lineIdx) + 1;
        SendMessage(GetParent(m_parent), CEM_GETLINEINFO, MAKEWPARAM(m_caretPos.line, m_caretPos.column), 0);
    }
    break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(m_self, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Call `DefSubclassProc` *before* studying the caret position. That lets you study the position after the edit control has processed the message.

Comment: Also, you're working too hard. Use `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` and `EM_LINEINDEX` rather than using the caret coordinates (which may not be valid if focus is lost to another window while you're calculating it).

Comment: If you can switch to a RichEdit control, then you can handle its [EN_SELCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-selchange) notification.

Comment: I will think about switching to a rich edit if it's not too different from the original EDIT control, this project is just for learning the API, so it doesn't matter what window I use as long as it does the job. Some things are updated, and everything works as expected (everything is handled in one place). EM_LINEFROMCHAR and EM_LINEINDEX seem to be excellent choices!